# React component structure

Tags: reactjs

React uses the component structure for writing the logical and view part in the same component. But why do they not separate the view part and logical part, As they do in angular2 or other frameworks?

There would be a special reason behind this, but I don't know the actual reason.

What is the benefit of component structure in react?

Comment: One component should do one thing and one thing only. Thus enabling code reuse and ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is common practice, but my team and I write two React components for every view. A `.component` for the logic and a `.presentation.component` for the UI. 
In my opinion it is definitely better to separate UI from logic, even in React.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in React it is commonplace to not have separation of concerns, like there is in Angular... Even inline styles are encouraged. You can find arguments for and against it in other sources.

Edit: Sometimes you look at your code and ask this question: presentational, logic, and styling take up 70 lines of code to express if I put it in one file. Why would I want to look at 3 different files to figure out what's going on?